# UITableView behaving differently in IOS 7 vs IOS 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios6, ios7

My UITtableView is behaving strangely on IOS 7, it is working fine on IOS 6. When using the searchbar to filter cells it appears as if there is an overlay of cells on top of each other. I dont know how to put this in words but here are the images

On IOS 7

[image: Image iOS 7]

On IOS 6

[image: image iOS 6]
Here is the code

```
#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView == self.tableView)
{
    return [self.airportArray count];
}
else
    return [filterArray count];
}

 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
      static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

      UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
      if (cell == nil)
      {
          cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
          cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
      }

       NSMutableDictionary *cDict;

      if (tableView == self.tableView)
      {
         cDict = [self.airportArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
      }
      else 
      {
         cDict = [filterArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
      }

     cell.textLabel.text = [cDict objectForKey:@"code4"];

     return cell;
}


#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSMutableDictionary *cDict;

    if (tableView == self.tableView) {
        cDict = [self.airportArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    else {
        cDict = [filterArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    if (_currentTextField == _viewController.diversion1TextField) {
        [_viewController setChooseAirport1:cDict];
    }
    else if (_currentTextField == _viewController.diversion2TextField)
    {
        [_viewController setChooseAirport2:cDict];
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting only iOS 6 image in your zip file.

Comment: You made cell reuse impossible. You should never ever do that.

Comment: Host the image at any provider link them here, someone will include that as images.

Comment: Images have been updated

Comment: How can I make cell reuse possible?

Comment: by not making it impossible. why don't you dequeue cells?

Comment: @vikingosegundo I have tried using that as well. But still no luck, let me check out link on the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hate to link to just a website as an answer but this is a bug in popover UISearchDisplayerControllers on iOS 7.0.

Peter Steinberger has documented pretty well here: [Fixing UISearchDisplayController on iOS 7](http://petersteinberger.com/blog/2013/fixing-uisearchdisplaycontroller-on-ios-7/)

Comment: Thank you very much Mark, I've spent almost 4 days fighting with this bug and it was driving me mad. You're my hero ;)

Answer (score 0):

you just have to remove comment of **[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];**

so your code look like

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
      ....
      UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
      ....
}
```

and is still not working then take a look of my code from http://sdrv.ms/IRaf5a

Comment: I have tried commenting this as well but still no luck, let me check out your link and let you know.

Comment: Same results. Does having ARC enabled make a difference? As you can see in the right most UITableView in the top image, the search is working correctly, the text "KSFO" is being filtered properly. But I dont understand why other cells are still being displayed. It is displaying fine on IOS 6 (bottom image)

Comment: Make sure that you have take UISearchBar and UISearchDisplayController in your xib or Storyboard file